# Tensorflow Normalization layer, update_states() does not update

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the Normalization layer in a model. I want to adapt it to my data before using it in the training. What I do is:

```py
prep_layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(name='normalization')
for x, y in data:
    if not prep_layer.is_adapted:
        prep_layer.adapt(x)
    else:
        prep_layer.update_state(x)
        print(f'Preprocess done. Mean={prep_layer.mean} and \
              Var={prep_layer.variance}.')
```

I expect the printed mean and variance to be different after every update but they stay exactly the same.

I tried to change the else statement to this:

```py
    else:
        prep_layer.update_state(np.ones(x.shape))
        print(f'Preprocess done. Mean={prep_layer.mean} and \
              Var={prep_layer.variance}.')
```

Which should push the mean towards 1 and variance towards 0. It does not. Seems like the layer does not change after adapt().

How do I correctly update the layer's mean and variance to my data using batching?

The 'data' is instance of tf.keras.utils.Sequence class and delivers (x , y) in a constant batch size.